# PHP: mkdir() not working

Tags: php, hosting

Any ideas of why mkdir is returning true but it's not creating any folder? Any way it could be blocked? How can I look at this? I have full cpanel access and root.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you checking whether the folder was created or not?

Comment: how are you setting the permission?

Comment: What user is the webserver running as? Does it have permission to create the folder? Generally web servers dont run as root. If you have shell access, you can su to the web user and see.

Comment: Use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) on the same path you're giving `mkdir` to check whether it was created. Chances are, your working directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: It's possible that you are creating the directory, but you don't have permission to access it.  Are you providing a mask value as the second parameter?

Comment: how can i know what is my working dir? Maybe it is doing something somewhere...

Comment: i used getcwd() and the working dir is correct... it's not creating the folder for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#99810):

> I failed to take into account an existing umask when I did a
>   `mkdir(dirname, 0755)`.  This ended up creating the directory
>   (function returned true), but I didn't have rights to do anything
>   inside the folder, nor could I even view that it existed via ftp.